# checklistbox display multi column

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using checklistbox control in windows forms.although after binding it, possibly it can have more than 100 s of items.so was thinking about displaying checklistbox in multiplecolumns 
so that it will be easy for user to select without scrolling a lot.
Is it possible?

Comment: I believe you can [use a ListView for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `MultiColumn` to `True` on your `CheckedListBox`.

```
checkedListBox1.MultiColumn = true;

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Item " + i);
}
```

[image]